# No sound with Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus Zenbook UX533FTC

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, sound, laptop, asus

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Asus Zenbook UX533FTC-A8178T laptop coming with Windows 10, in dual boot.

**No sound comes out from the speakers, or the headphones jack** (while in Windows sound is ok).

I previously tried with 18.04 and it didn't work either. For several days I browsed similar "no sound questions", but it didn't work out.
So now I freshly re-installed ubuntu 20.04, updated it, and installed pavucontrol, and inxi only for a fresh start.

Hoping someone can help I put some useful information below.

Thanks, Filippo

(PS I tried manjaro-gnome-19.0.2-200312-linux54.iso, while with Ubuntu 18.04 I tried different kernels: 4.19.0, 4.19.10, 4.19.43 etc etc)

- `uname -a`

```
Linux ZenBook 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- `alsamixer`

```
AlsaMixer v1.1.3 ────────────────────────────────────────

│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                                                   
│ Chip: Realtek ALC294                                                    
│ View: F3:[Playback]
```

Everything is on, "OO", Auto-Mute is disabled

- `inxi -SMAG`

```
System:    Host: ZenBook Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ZenBook UX534FTC_UX533FTC v: 1.0 
           serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX534FTC v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: UX534FTC.304 date: 12/16/2019 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nouveau resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-26-generic
```

- `pavucontrol`

```
Output devices: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
Port: Speakers (on which I can see the audio bar moving when playing a youtube video)
Configuration: Analog Stereo Duplex/Analog Stereo Output (same thing)
```

- `cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Comment: Can it be a dualboot issue? May be removing Windows and installing Ubuntu as single-OS can solve problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I think it may be a dual boot issue. For example when i boot to windows coming from ubuntu the clock shifts two hours back. The problem is that I need to have Windows as well. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution or workaround? I have UX533FTC laptop and no sound as well. No, it's not dualboot issue. I've created thread in Arch Linux forums too https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255446 but seems it's missing support within the kernel, so we need to patiently wait for a upstream fix...

Comment: Still no workaround, sorry!

Comment: About your clock issue it's because linux and windows do not use the same time. Check 
https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/
it should solve your time problem (no idea for sound though)

Answer (score 3):

I also have an issue with dualboot windows 10 / ubuntu 20.
My issue with sound happens every time I switch from windows to ubuntu or the opposite.
Haven't find a definitive solution yet, but I discovered that entering the bios menu and leaving it before starting with the other operating system allows to avoid the problem.
So each time I reboot with a different operating system, I open the bios setup first, exit the bio setup, and boot with the different operating system. I have no issue when I reboot the operating system I used last...

Comment: I've heard of that one too.

Comment: Hi, this does not work for me, and I have the issue only on Linux.

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for this? Because this is exactly what happens to me and this work around fixes it

Comment: It was exactly the fix for me too. Thank you so much! I have windows 10 + ubuntu 20.04 on asus zenbook duo

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the headphone jack (don't use it) but this is what fixed the issue with no sound on the inboard speakers on my Asus Zenbook UX534FTC running Ubuntu 20.04.

https://www.linux.org/threads/asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/post-94194

Only thing I did differently was that I put the script in /etc/rc.local to make it runs at startup (personal preference).

Almost forgot, you also need to install alsa-tools if you haven't already.

Good luck!

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did and managed to get the audio back on. I don't boot 'Ubuntu' directly from 'Boot menu' but choose 'Setup' instead and override boot in 'Save&Exit' tab.

1. Hold Esc at the start to open [Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoDqS.jpg) (may differ on different laptop), choose 'Enter setup'.
2. In [Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDhWd.jpg), Move to 'Save & Exit' tab
3. In 'Boot override', choose 'Ubuntu', Enter.

FYI, my laptop is ASUS ZenBook UX433FA. That's all. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I solved this issue with commands from here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850439/comments/163

(I found it via https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/#post-94194)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Asus UX533, but thanks to [@Sri](https://askubuntu.com/users/859386/sri) it's solved now.

The solution in simple steps:

- Create a script to run with each reboot

  ```
    sudo nano /etc/rc.local
  ```
- Then paste the following:

  ```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
    exit 0
  ```
- Then press `CTRL + X`  Then press `Y` Then press `Enter`
- Give the script execute permissions:

  ```
    sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
  ```
- Restart your device

Answer (score 0):

disabling secure boot helped with lots of issues, including sound

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an Asus UX435 here. After using Windows, in order to get sound when I next boot into Linux, I found I have do the following:

- Shut down Windows (not restart)
- Remove the power cord
- Start the machine, and boot into Linux (kernels 4.19 and 5.10 work here)
- After boot, log in to KDE
- Once the desktop environment has loaded, the sound will be working, and I can plug the power back in